# Converting urllib2 POST to Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an existing Http POST using urllib2:

```
data = 'client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&grant_type=authorization_code&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s' % (settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, code, redirect_uri)

req = urllib2.Request(access_token_url, data=data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response_content = response.read()

json_response = json.loads(response_content)
```

I'm trying to convert this to the Requests library instead (http://docs.python-requests.org/) but I'm getting a 400 Invalid Request.

Here's my attempt:

```
params = {'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri}
params['client_id'] = settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
params['client_secret'] =  settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
params['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code'
params['code'] = code

req = requests.post(access_token_url, data=params)
json_response = req.json()
```

I tried tweaking it to use params instead of data but I got the same error.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Shouldn't be the correct call being `req = requests.post(access_token_url, params=params)`

Comment: I tried params but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you edit your question to insert the full error message. Do you have tried to capture network activity using a tool like Wireshark to examine the request in order to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I just get a Response Code 400 & message is "Invalid Request".

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Is this not a valid question?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values of the data dict are not already escaped as `requests` will do that for you. Please notice how your original example does not do any escaping.